# Database driver error >>The character " " following "ÃãÉåÉãèmÉÄ@" is not valid<< during session execution

Tags: database, db2, informatica-powercenter, informatica

I am getting below error at session level. kindly help me to fix this -

> READER_1_1_1> RR_4035 SQL Error [
>   [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] **SQL0007N  The character " " following "ÃãÉåÉãèmÉÄ@" is not valid.**
>   SQLSTATE=42601
>   sqlstate = 42601
>   Database driver error...

I have written a SQL query in source qualifier. Query is fetching data from three tables, so join is there,condition is there and sub-query is also. While validating in source qualifier, it not giving any error and even running this query in toad, it is running fine.

So why I am getting this error at session level? Is it because query has sub-queries or some connection issues with DB?

My DB is DB2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost certain you have an encoding issue. Your SQL is probably being encoded as UTF-8 (just by inspection of the junk in your error message), but the driver is expecting something else.

Try specifying the encoding you're using to the driver, or use the encoding that the driver expects